# Readonly Strategies with Nhibernate and Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I been reading nhibernate for beginners 3.0 and been reading about common mistakes(a few of them I been making)

I am wondering what are some strategies for making one or more records readonly. Right now I get all the rows back and loop through them making them readonly through session.Readonly().

I like in the book that they do with fluent

```
class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        SchemaAction.None();
        ReadOnly();

        // Mappings
    }
 }
```

What I am not sure is what happens if I need these records to not be Readonly? To me this means I have to make this exact same mapping minus those 2 lines of code.

So I would like to do this and have ReadonlyEntityMap and EntityMap but I rather not have to duplicate all the settings twice.

Anyone have ideas on how do to this? Or better ideas for readonly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ReadOnly()` on your mapping will disable any updates back to the database when you modify the properties of the object.

If you want to apply some sort of ReadOnly and Writeable strategy I would suggest using a [Fluent Convention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions) and a marker interface or similar.

You can also apply `ReadOnly()` to a property if you want to disable writes on just that one property. I use that technique to avoid writing back to Computed Columns in SQL Server.

Something like this:

```
public interface IReadOnly{} //Mark entities with this interface

public class ReadOnlyConvention
     : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance<IClassInspector>
{
  public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
  {
    criteria.Expect(x => x.EntityType Is IReadOnly);
  }

  public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
  {
    instance.ReadOnly();
  }
}
```

Update:
If you want to do you time conversion thing I would suggest creating an IUserType for your DateTime object which does the conversion to the user time without modifying the underlying data.

- [Date Time Support in NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/26/date-time-support-in-nhibernate.aspx)
- [Custom IUserType for DateTime](http://randomcode.net.nz/2009/10/16/simplify-iusertype-testing/)

Comment: How does the Readonly get set?

Comment: It gets applied at the same time you configure NHibernate in App_Start or whatever. See the bottom of this wiki page: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions

Comment: but how do I tell it I want it to be readonly when I get back under this scenario vs another scenario where I don't want it to be readonly?

Comment: So you have one class and depending on some circumstances you want it to be readonly some of the time? `session.Evict(yourobject)` will stop the object from writing back changes. Just put the logic in your dataccess layer or use Dimitry's idea of Stateless Session. Maybe some more code from you would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to optimize memory consumption you should consider improving your session management strategy or using [other performance improvement techniques.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html) You can for example:

- Clear the session that loaded your objects and it will release all the memory allocated by first level cache. The objects can later be reattached (Merged) to a new session if needed. This way you don't need objects to be readonly in the first place.
- Evict some of the objects when you no longer need them. This will keep the other objects in the first level cache.
- Use [IStatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession)  which does not use 1st level cache at all.

Again, the answer depends on your application architecture.

Comment: Well what I have right now is this. I get one or more rows back. these rows have datetimes as one of the columns(stored in utc). To make life easy as soon as I get the result back all the datetimes are converted into the users local time. After the find method is done you don't have to think about what timezone these records are in as it is users local time. However according to nhibernate an update has occured and if a commit happens these times get saved back into the db and all the datetimes are no messed up. So right now I loop through all of them and make them readonly.

Comment: You can clear the session or evict these objects so that NHibernate session does not know about them anymore and will not try to update  the database for these objects. Alternatively you can store converted date in the field/property that is not mapped. This way NHibernate would not even know about it and would not consider the object to be updated.

Comment: Hmm I guess that is an option. The thing with evict is still I have to loop through all the objects in the collect. This is what is what I am trying to stop. Kinda sucks you get back 50 objects and the first thing you have to do is loop over each one and evict or make them readonly or whatever

Comment: The underlying problem is that you convert and read the same property that you read from database. Consider mapping original date as private field and maybe have to properties like OriginalDate and LocalDate where LocalDate will do the conversion internally.